# Facebook login with localhost not working

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am using facebook login in Java web application.

Redirect URL is `http://<localhost>:8080/` as it's in dev mode.

But I am getting the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application. Invalid application ID.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

I am using Spring Social Project with `facebook.clientId` and `facebook.clientSecret`, which are App ID and App Secret from https://developers.facebook.com/apps which seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Replace localhost to your live ip, it will work and change the web site facebook login on facebook site